# $\lim_{n\to \infty}\dfrac{\sum\limits_{k=2}^n k\cos\dfrac{π}{k}}{n^2} $

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, trigonometry, summation

Find the value of 
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\dfrac{\sum\limits_{k=2}^n k\cos\dfrac{π}{k}}{n^2} $$

Please help me, I can't find any clues..

Answer (score 2):

Over the interval $\left[0,\frac{\pi}{2}\right]$ we have that $\cos x$ is bounded between $1-\frac{x^2}{2}$ and $1-\frac{4x^2}{\pi^2}$.
It follows that $S(n)=\sum_{k=2}^{n}k\cos\frac{\pi}{k}$ is bounded between
$$ \sum_{k=2}^{n}k-\frac{\pi^2}{2}\sum_{k=2}^{n}\frac{1}{k} = \frac{n^2}{2}+O(n)$$
and
$$ \sum_{k=2}^{n}k-4\sum_{k=2}^{n}\frac{1}{k} = \frac{n^2}{2}+O(n)$$
and the wanted limit is clearly $\color{red}{\large\frac{1}{2}}$ by squeezing.

Answer (score 1):

By Stolz-Cesaro, your limit is equal with

$$
\lim_{n\to \infty}\dfrac{\sum\limits_{k=2}^n k\cos\dfrac{π}{k}}{n^2}=\lim_{n\to \infty}\dfrac{\sum\limits_{k=2}^{n+1} k\cos\dfrac{π}{k}-\sum\limits_{k=2}^n k\cos\dfrac{π}{k}}{2n+1}\\
=\lim_{n\to \infty}\dfrac{(n+1)\cos\dfrac{π}{n+1}}{2n+1}
$$
which is easy to calculate.

Comment: Could you show me another way as I've not learned about Stolz theorem..

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
&\lim_{n\to \infty}\bracks{{1 \over n^{2}}\sum_{k = 2}^{n}k\cos\pars{π \over k}} =
\lim_{n\to \infty}\braces{{1 \over n^{2}}\sum_{k = 2}^{n}k -
{1 \over n^{2}}\sum_{k = 2}^{n}k\bracks{1 - \cos\pars{π \over k}}}
\\[5mm] = &\
\lim_{n\to \infty}\bracks{{1 \over 2} + {1 \over 2n} - {1 \over n^{2}} -
{2 \over n^{2}}\sum_{k = 2}^{n}k\sin^{2}\pars{π \over 2k}} = \bbx{1 \over 2}
\end{align}

> Note that
>   $\ds{0 < \verts{{2 \over n^{2}}\sum_{k = 2}^{n}k\sin^{2}\pars{π \over 2k}} <
> {\pi^{2} \over 2n^{2}}\sum_{k = 2}^{n}{1 \over k} =
> {\pi^{2} \over 2}\,{H_{n} - 1 \over n^{2}}
> \,\,\,\stackrel{\mrm{as}\ n\ \to\ \infty}{\to}\,\,\,\color{#f00}{\large 0}}$.
>   
>  The *Harmonic Number* $\ds{\quad H_{n} \,\,\,\stackrel{\mrm{as}\ n\ \to\ \infty}{\sim}\,\,\,{\large\ln\pars{n}}}$.